# Custom libraries in Eclipse with Arduino plugin with cross references

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have an issue with custom libraries that reference headers in other custom libraries.
This is under Eclipse (2020-03) with the 9.11 CDT - Arduino Plugins. (So the latest Version at this time)

Until now I have been using Sloeber, which included all include paths from all custom libraries so everythig was building fine. But with the latest Eclipse/CDT version sloeber does not work anymore. Since it should not really be necessary anymore anyway, I am trying to get my projects to build with just the CDT-Arduino Plugin(s).
Simple projects are Building fine, but more complex have issues…

The build process (makefile generation) seems to scan though the libraries directory, because I can see all the entries in the makefile to build the things it findes in there. But I one of these libraries referneces a header of another one it failes to find it. 
Of course I could just edit the include and make it relative, but since these are imported libraries I prefer not to make changes in the code.

With the Arduino plugin there is also no configuration for include paths etc in the project properties any more :-( Normally I would have added the include path there, but the arduino Plugin seems to want to do it all by itself...

Any idea, how I can add the required include paths? Is there a way to do this in the makefile.ini?

Answer (score 0):

I found a different and better way to add custom libraries, which also solves the include path problem. Sadly there is no documentaion about this.

Anyway, it is very simple, just copy the library to the …/.arduinocdt/libraries/ folder. The custom library must contain a library.jason and library.properties file. When opening the Arduino download manager, you can see the new lib and ýou can add it.
Eclipse will read the library version from the json/properties and copy the data in the correct form in a sub directory with the version number.

For libraries added this way, all includes/headers will be found without Problems including libraries referencing other libraries.